# On 16.10, I keep getting "waiting to install" error message for direct installation of any app (e.g., google chrome)

Tags: 16.10

A simple download and install of any application on ubuntu desktop 16.10 hangs indefinitely with "waiting to install"

Answer (score 0):

use app grid or synaptic or apt-get.software center is usually like that.

To install chromium ( the open source chrome without flash):

open a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+T or pressing windows key and searching for terminal.

type

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

type your password. you won't see anything while you type. just type and press enter. it will ask for confirmation again. type 'y' without quotes and press enter. it will download and install chromium.

but if you want graphical package manager. open a terminal as above and type

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

synaptic is a well rated package manager.

if you want chrome, then, download the deb file from its site .
install gdebi from synaptic. and open the deb file with gdebi which will take care of dependencies and install it for you.